# PHP - Simpletest - Comparing numeric strings

Tags: php, simpletest

I'm trying to use simpletest to compare two numeric strings, one from an array and one from an object property.

I've printed out the values and they are equal, however, the test always returns false.
Can anyone help?

Here's the code:

```
$this->assertEqual(strval($this->createdforums[$randomforum]),
(strval($forum->getTitle)));

   print_r($this->createdforums[$randomforum]);
   print_r('<br />');
   print_r($forum->getTitle());
```

The values that get printed out are:

1250833961
1250833961

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the brackets off getTitle in the assert. should be...

```
$this->assertEqual(strval($this->createdforums[$randomforum]),
(strval($forum->getTitle())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some spaces around the values. Try to trim() them before comparing.